# Problem with \doublerulesepcolor in colortbl

Tags: colortbl

I would like a table where the background of the first line is gray and the background of the rest of the table is white. The problem is
that the table has a double column line. I have tried `\doublerulesepcolor` but it allows me to put color between the two column lines for ALL the table and not for just the first line.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
\definecolor{Lightgray}{gray}{.80}
\doublerulesepcolor{Lightgray}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c||c|}\hline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} CityFrom & CityTo & Count\\\hline
 \doublerulesepcolor{white}
 a & c & 2\\
 a & e & 1\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{verbatim}

\begin{center}
\definecolor{Lightgray}{gray}{.80}
\doublerulesepcolor{Lightgray}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c||c|}\hline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} CityFrom & CityTo & Count\\\hline
 \doublerulesepcolor{white}
 a & c & 2\\
 a & e & 1\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

While trying to solve the problem I realized that \verb+\arrayrulecolor+ can be changed at each line
but this not the case with \verb+\doublerulesepcolor+

\begin{verbatim}
\definecolor{Lightgray}{gray}{.80}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\doublerulesepcolor{Lightgray}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c||c|}\hline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} CityFrom & CityTo & Count\\\hline
 \arrayrulecolor{red}\doublerulesepcolor{red}
 a & c & 2\\
 \arrayrulecolor{blue}\doublerulesepcolor{blue} 
 a & e & 1\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{verbatim}

\begin{center}
\definecolor{Lightgray}{gray}{.80}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\doublerulesepcolor{Lightgray}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c||c|}\hline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} CityFrom & CityTo & Count\\\hline
 \arrayrulecolor{red}\doublerulesepcolor{red}
 a & c & 2\\
 \arrayrulecolor{blue}\doublerulesepcolor{blue} 
 a & e & 1\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

What is needed is that \verb+\doublerulesepcolor+ has a ``local" behavior as \verb+\arrayrulecolor+.

Any hint how to obtain this ?

Regards

Esteban

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er, sorry, this appears to be an *undocumented feature*.

Add this to the document preamble

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@mkpream\@mkpream
\def\@mkpream{%
\ifx\CT@drsc@\relax\else\let\CT@drsc@ @\fi
\let\CT@arc@\relax
\old@mkpream}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c||c|}[colortbl-like]
 \hline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} CityFrom & CityTo & Count\\\hline
 a & c & 2\\
 a & e & 1\\\hline
 \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I have used the key `colortbl-like` in order to be able to use color the row with a command `\rowcolor` with a syntax similar to the syntax of the corresponding command of `colortbl`.

However, it's also possible to put the instructions for the color of the rows, columns and cells before the main array, in the `\CodeBefore`.

[image: Output of the above code]