# colortbl: why does a double vertical line interrupt the background color?

Tags: line, colortbl, vertical

Feeding

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\(\begin{array}{l|l|l||l|l|l}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26
  \end{array}\)
\end{document}
```

leads to the background coloring of the header being interrupted by the double vertical line:

[image: output]

Between the two lines composing the double line, the background color is white.  A bug or a feature?  This is unwanted as fas as my particular output is concerned; any way to get the space between the two lines in the upper row colored, too?  I tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137394 , but the solution from there seems to have no effect for my input as of today.

Yes, I know we could use the package nicematrix and say `\begin{NiceArray}{l|l|l||l|l|l}[colortbl-like]\rowcolor[gray]{.9} …\end{NiceArray}` at the cost of an extra run, and that's why my question concerns `colortbl` only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On TeX Live 2020, using colortbl 2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC), the hack provided by David Carlisle (DPC) in his [answer to "Problem with \doublerulesepcolor in colortbl"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137394/118714) works out as long as `\doublerulesepcolor` is called and thus `\CT@drsc@` is defined differently from `\relax` before doing `\begin{array}`. If this is done, with the hack you can apply `\doublerulesepcolor` for explicitly specifying colors within the `array`-environment also.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter
% The hack by David Carlisle, the author of colortbl, see
% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137394>
\let\old@mkpream\@mkpream
\def\@mkpream{%
\ifx\CT@drsc@\relax\else\let\CT@drsc@ @\fi
\let\CT@arc@\relax
\old@mkpream}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
%\pagecolor{yellow}%
\(%
    \doublerulesepcolor{green}%<-something to make sure \CT@drsc@ is defined different from \relax
    \begin{array}{l|l|l||l|l|l}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    \doublerulesepcolor[gray]{.9}%
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    \doublerulesepcolor{white}%
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26
   \end{array}%
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

*Addendum on August 12, 2022:*

- If some background-color is already in effect, e.g., due to `\pagecolor`, then setting color "white" explicitly as `\doublerulesepcolor` versus not setting another color for the horizontal/vertical space between the rules of a double-rule at all makes a difference.
- With some printing machines it makes a difference whether you explicitly set "white" as (background) color or set that no (other) (background) color should be used.

  For example, if you send a print job from the PC to the color printer that prints things on paper, and in the pdf file the background color for some text is explicitly set to "white", then it normally does not happen that white background color is printed on white paper. Thus, with these devices, the background is not really white, but the background is in the color of the paper to be printed on. (To be honest, I don't know whether inkjet printers, let alone color laser printers, can produce white color at all, and I doubt it, but maybe I am wrong.) But if you use a machine that prints on plexiglas panes, for example, then white background color is printed as well, and it makes a difference whether in the pdf-file you set to print white (background) color or set to use no (background) color at all.

If, instead of switching to text color "white", you wish to specify that no different color at all shall be used, you might redefine the command `\CT@drsc@` in such a way that it doesn't change the text color and then draws rules in the text color, but takes those tokens out of the token stream which represent the commands for drawing the rules and replaces them with tokens to create corresponding horizontal/vertical spaces /`\hskip`s/`\vskip`s.

The following is a first attempt. However, I have only briefly skimmed the source code of colortbl and therefore cannot guarantee that it really works correctly all the time. Someone more experienced than me could judge this better.

A better strategy for "turning off" color might be to introduce a flag for each kind of color element, e.g., an \if-switch or a `\@firstoftwo`/`\@secondoftwo` thing, which determines if anything colorful should be done at all or only corresponding `\hskip`/`\vskip` should be inserted.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% The hack by David Carlisle, the author of colortbl, see
% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137394>
\let\old@mkpream\@mkpream
\def\@mkpream{%
\ifx\CT@drsc@\relax\else\let\CT@drsc@ @\fi
\let\CT@arc@\relax
\old@mkpream}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\CT@drsc@NoDoublerulesepcolor{%
  \@ifnextchar\vrule{%
    \@firstoftwo{%
      \@ifnextchar{w}{\expandafter\hskip\@gobblewidth}%
                     {\expandafter\hskip\@gobble}%
    }%
  }{%
    \@ifnextchar\hrule{%
      \@firstoftwo{%
        \@ifnextchar{h}{\expandafter\vskip\@gobbleheight}%
                       {\expandafter\vskip\@gobble}%
      }%
    }{%
      \@ifnextchar\leaders{\@gobbleto@height}{}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\def\@gobblewidth width{}%
\def\@gobbleheight height{}%
\def\@gobbleto@height\leaders\hrule\@height#1{\leaders\vbox to#1{}}%
\newcommand\NoDoublerulesepcolor{\noalign{\global\let\CT@drsc@\CT@drsc@NoDoublerulesepcolor}}
\newcommand\InitDoublerulesepcolor{%
  \gdef\CT@drsc@{}%
  \global\let\CT@drsc@\CT@drsc@NoDoublerulesepcolor
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\pagecolor{yellow}%
\(%
    \InitDoublerulesepcolor
    \begin{array}{l|l|l||l|l|l}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    \doublerulesepcolor[gray]{.9}%
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    \NoDoublerulesepcolor
    \hline
    \hline
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26
   \end{array}%
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you use the command `\pagecolor` for setting a background-color of the page, the two examples behave differently:

With the first example color between double-rules in the second table-row is white anyway because the color "white" is set explicitly, **which is likely to be not what you want(!!!)**.

With the second example color between double-rules in the second table-row is the background-color of the page because instead of (colored) rules `\hskips`/`\vskips` and `\leaders` containing empty boxes of specified height are used.
*(By the way, with my second example I was surprised that using an empty `\vbox` and thus a box of width 0pt works out with `\leaders` for `\hfill`. A box of width 0pt should fit into horizontal space infinitely many times... Probably I overlooked something in the TeXbook...)*

Output of first example with `\pagecolor{yellow}`:

[image]

Output of second example with `\pagecolor{yellow}`:

[image]

Comment: It turns out, you can even say `\doublerulesepcolor{}` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, your second suggestion does not quite jive because it influences the following arrays. E.g., https://pastebin.com/raw/vygzHiQq (set to expire after 1 a) results in https://i.imgur.com/cfbLUpN.png . There, the double rule of the following array is completely black inside.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Probably `\newcommand\InitDoublerulesepcolor{\gdef\CT@drsc@{}\global\let\CT@drsc@\CT@drsc@NoDoublerulesepcolor}` instead of `\newcommand\InitDoublerulesepcolor{\gdef\CT@drsc@{}}` (incorporatinbg the actions of `\NoDoublerulesepcolor` into `\InitDoublerulesepcolor`) does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because of how background coloring works (not just in `colortbl` but in `tabularray` and other packages as well)—that is, it colors individual cells and not the row as a whole. Since the space between the double vertical line is not in a cell, you can’t give it a background color.

One possible workaround would be to do something ugly like replacing `||` with `|@{}c@{}|` and having an empty column where the double bar occurs and then insert the spacing for between the double rows in one row with `\hspace*{2pt}`.

(Note that this is untested and may not work and the dimension that I gave might be wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its key `colortbl-like`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{exterior-arraycolsep}

\begin{document}

\(\begin{NiceArray}{l|l|l||l|l|l}[colortbl-like]
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26
  \end{NiceArray}\)

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

---

*Remark*

By default, `{NiceArray}` does not put the `\arraycolsep` on both sides of the array.

In the documentation of `amsmath`, we read:

> The extra space of \arraycolsep that array adds on each
> side is a waste so we remove it [in {matrix}] (perhaps we should instead
> remove it from array in general, but that’s
> a harder task).

That's why I have decided to remove them in `{NiceArray}`. But there is a key in `\NiceMatrixOptions` in order to roll back to a behavior similar to `{array}`.

Comment: First, thanks! Second, I quote from my original post: “[…] my question concerns colortbl only.” Third, thx for the the explanation about `\arraycolsep` on both sides!